# What are my options implementing a tree data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I need a tree structure for one of my programs. I know of the following two approaches to implement one:

1. Recursive, pointer based.

```cpp
struct node
{
    std::unique_ptr<T>                 data     = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> children = {};
};

//       /> leaf_a
// root --> leaf_b  /> leaf_d
//       \> leaf_c --> leaf_e
auto root = std::make_unique<node>();
root->children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node>(a_data));
root->children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node>(b_data));
root->children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node>(c_data));
root->children[2]->children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node>(d_data));
root->children[2]->children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<node>(e_data));
```

2. Node pair based.

```cpp
struct tree
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>        data        = {};
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> connections = {};
};


//       /> leaf_a
// root --> leaf_b  /> leaf_d
//       \> leaf_c --> leaf_e
auto boom = tree{};
boom.data.emplace_back(nullptr);
boom.data.emplace_back(a_data);
boom.data.emplace_back(b_data);
boom.data.emplace_back(c_data);
boom.data.emplace_back(d_data);
boom.data.emplace_back(e_data);
boom.connections.emplace_back(std::make_pair(0,1));
boom.connections.emplace_back(std::make_pair(0,2));
boom.connections.emplace_back(std::make_pair(0,3));
boom.connections.emplace_back(std::make_pair(3,4));
boom.connections.emplace_back(std::make_pair(3,5));
```

Of course, both examples could be made much prettier with the appropriate api, but they are only supposed to show the most basic implementation.

**My question is:** *Are there any other approaches to implement a tree? What would be the pro/cons either appraoch?*

**Note:** I explictly need the option to have multiple children per node, and each node is supposed to have an optional data field.

Comment: Personally, I'd outsource the work ;) https://github.com/kpeeters/tree.hh

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: If you have the added very strong assumption that the tree is an almost-complete binary tree, then you can conveniently store it in an array. That is how [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) are usually implemented.

Comment: A third possibility is to have each child point to its parent (and the root points to NULL), rather than each parent point to a list of its children.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` pointing to child nodes is not necessarily a good idea (there is a risk of stack overflow on destruction). `std::unique_ptr<T> data = nullptr;` is the *billion dollar mistake*. Use `T data;` and forward the constructor arguments. If your *specific* tree is a tree of pointers, use `node<std::unique_ptr<whatever>>`, but this should be very rare.

Comment: @Stef I was looking at binary trees again. Apparently it is possible to unroll n-ary trees into binary trees, However, on pays with more complicated access... Your second option is interesting. This would be a mixture of both 1. and 2. because I would need to keep a list of all nodes somewhere. In principle one could even store a pointer to both the children and the parent.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sorry. This is a typo. It should of course read `std::make_unique<T>`. I will fix this. For the `data` field I cannot use `T data` because it is supposed to be optional.

Comment: Why should your *generic code* care? Use `node<std::optional>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other approaches to implement a tree?

All your options deal with dynamic memory and won't play nice with cache coherency, will incur extra indirections. This is definitely opinion-based, but I'll give you another option

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
    T value;
    std::vector<size_t> children; // position in nodes of the children
};

template <typename T>
class Tree
{
    std::vector<Node<T>> nodes;
};
```

This has all the nodes in a contiguous block and would allow re-parenting nodes without copying them around. It would come with extra complexity for adding, removing, etc.

But it's an extra option. It even allows exotic trees with cycles :-)

Comment: The OP requires that each node can have N leaves.

Comment: Edited. Makes it a bit less simple, though. Maybe children could be an array of templated size. Plenty of options.

Comment: Very interesting! Your option is similar to my second one, but make it much easier to find the children of each node, which should be good for tree traversal.

Comment: For the actual use case I am thinking about, I will spend quite a lot of time iterating through the tree and replacing nodes with an expanded version. Currently my idea in terms of memory behavior is to push new nodes back into a `std::deque`. This would allow me to extend the tree without copying. For deletion I would need to keep an extra list of deleted nodes, which I would remove after all the other steps are finished. But needs to be tested and benchmarked of course.